# Mount CIFS share with autofs

Tags: redhat, cifs, autofs, automount

I have a system running RHEL 5.5, and I am trying to mount a Windows share on a server using `autofs`.  (Due to the network not being ready upon startup, I do not want to utilize `fstab`.)  I am able to mount the shares manually, but `autofs` is just not mounting them.

Here are the files I am working with:

At the end of `/etc/auto.master`, I have:

```
## Mount this test share:
/test    /etc/auto.test    --timeout=60
```

In `/etc/auto.test`, I have:

```
test    -fstype=cifs,username=testuser,domain=domain.com,password=password ://server/test
```

I then restart the `autofs` service.

However, this does not work.  `ls`-ing the directory does not return any results.  I have followed all these guides on the web, and I either don't understand them, or they.just.don't.work.

Thank You

Comment: Are you getting anything in the logs?

Comment: Where are the logs?  I have tried `/var/log/messages` to no avail, and there is no syslog file.

Comment: You are looking in the right place. Try "echo 1 >/proc/fs/cifs/cifsFYI" to increase the debug messages a bit and give dmesg a try.

Comment: I don't have the `/proc/fs/cifs/` directory, so I cannot run the command. I also can't `mkdir cifs`, even as root. The service is running, but I seriously don't know why it's just not working. I may have to contact RH support.

Comment: Forget the proc location. Do you even have the module installed? Run this. ls -al /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/fs/cifs you should see cifs.ko

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There should be an /etc/auto.smb already, use that, and add the following line to /etc/auto.master:

```
/cifs   /etc/auto.smb --timeout=60
```

Now all cifs shares will show up under /cifs:

```
ls /cifs/<server>
```

will show all the shares available.  You might want to put some options in /etc/auto.smb to mount with specific modes.  I have a auto.smb that I found out there somewhere and modified to do exactly that:

```
#!/bin/bash
# $Id: auto.smb,v 1.3 2005/04/05 13:02:09 raven Exp $
# This file must be executable to work! chmod 755!

key="$1"
credfile="/etc/auto.smb.$key"

opts="-fstype=cifs,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,uid=eng,gid=eng"
smbclientopts=""

for P in /bin /sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin
do
    if [ -x $P/smbclient ]
    then
        SMBCLIENT=$P/smbclient
        break
    fi
done

[ -x $SMBCLIENT ] || exit 1

if [ -e "$credfile" ]
then
    opts=$opts",credentials=$credfile"
    smbclientopts="-A "$credfile
else
    smbclientopts="-N"
fi

$SMBCLIENT $smbclientopts -gNL $key 2>/dev/null| awk -v key="$key" -v opts="$opts" -F'|' -- '
    BEGIN   { ORS=""; first=1 }
    /Disk/  {
              if (first)
                  print opts; first=0
              dir = $2
              loc = $2
              # Enclose mount dir and location in quotes
              # Double quote "$" in location as it is special
              gsub(/\$$/, "\\$", loc);
              print " \\\n\t \"/" dir "\"", "\"://" key "/" loc "\""
            }
    END     { if (!first) print "\n"; else exit 1 }
'
```

This will do what you want.  I've used it myself.

Comment: Thank you.  I have completely forgotten about this issue.  I actually contacted Red hat support, and the options you mention in the opts you mention do work.  The key was to place the info in `auto.misc` for whatever reason.  It's funny, since we don't even need to do this anymore.

Comment: This is useful, but unfortunately I don't get to customize the mount points, which was the original goal of the question (and what I came here to find out)

Comment: As an interesting development, using this with an EMC device (not sure module) required me to remove the -N from the smbclient line.  Encountered this problem today.

Comment: Also, the credentials file must not have spaces between the equals signs.  That caused a bunch of errors until I found that out.  Two different pieces of documentation said different things.

Answer (score 10):

Since I just spent my entire morning debugging this same issue. Let me explain what happened above.

**/etc/auto.master**

```
## Mount this test share:
/test    /etc/auto.test    --timeout=60
```

This means I want to mount something at `/test` and for the details read `/etc/auto.test`

**/etc/auto.test**

```
test    -fstype=cifs,username=testuser,domain=domain.com,password=password ://server/test
```

This means as a sub-folder of what was specified in auto.master please mount test with the information following. (i.e. **the mount will be `/test/test`** as slm correctly pointed out).

This means that `ls /test/test` will display the contents of `//server/test`

To accomplish the original goal of /test -> //server/test you would want the following:

**/etc/auto.master**

```
## Mount this test share:
/    /etc/auto.test    --timeout=60
```

A couple other notes. I found the following mount options useful.

`rw` - mount it read/write

`noserverino` - removes error message about inode number support

`credentials=[credential file]` - this allows you to create a separate file with the credentials in them. It has the following format:

```
username=[windows username, domain can be included as well]
password=[windows password]
```

**EDIT -- 2013-06-17 13:28PM GMT-8**

slm in the comments has pointed out that mounting to the root of the file system could be dangerous. lsd in the comments suggests a workaround, which is to creating a symlink from the root of the filesystem to a different place where you would mount that would not overlap with something common. For example, if you wanted to have /test be a mount, then you would actually mount stuff to /net/the_test_mount and then create a symlink /test that points to /net/the_test_mount

Comment: This is dangerous in the sense that if someone were to add usr or etc for example to /etc/auto.test that these mounts would effectively override those directories on the system. Granted that's highly unlikely but in general mounts are not done at the root level.

Comment: Is there a better way to provide a root mount using autofs? If so please update your answer or leave a comment and I can update mine.

Comment: Have the mounts go to /net, say, and have symbolic links from /test to /net/server/test (or whatever).  Now whenever you cd to /net and ls or whatever, it will mount.

Answer (score 4):

I just did this on a CentOS 5.6 box and I think part of your problem might be with your auto.test file. In it's current form you'll be creating a /test mount point and then a single moung of test under it, i.e. /test/test. Also you might want to add the --ghost switch to your auto.master line like so:

```
/test    /etc/auto.test    --timeout=60 --ghost
```

The --ghost switch creates stubs of mount points even when a given share isn't being actively mounted.

Take a look at this [CentOS wiki Tips and Tricks page](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/WindowsShares) on ways to mount SMB/CIFS shares.

#### Mounting tips

- Windows Share = \mysmb\share1
- Unix Dir.     = /test/dir1

**idea #1**

```
 # /etc/auto.master
/test                 /etc/auto.test --timeout=600 --ghost

# /etc/auto.test
dir1         -fstype=cifs,rw,noperm,netbiosname=${HOST},credentials=/etc/creds.txt ://mysmb/test/dir1
dir2         -fstype=cifs,rw,noperm,netbiosname=${HOST},credentials=/etc/creds.txt ://mysmb/test/dir2
```

**idea #2**

```
 # /etc/auto.master
/test                 /etc/auto.test --timeout=600 --ghost

# /etc/auto.test
*            -fstype=cifs,rw,noperm,netbiosname=${HOST},credentials=/etc/creds.txt ://mysmb/test/&
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Please see my comment for lsd.

Comment: My god... --ghost should be default. I'm on fedora/rhel/centos it reads the map, but when I go inside the folder, nothing is there... I then had the crazy idea of doing `cd "sharename"` and it magically entered the folder which `ls` says does not exist... arrgh

Answer (score -1):

If you are using cifs it's recommended also to use `_netdev` parameter.

`_netdev` it's because the filesystem resides on a device that requires network access, this is used to prevent the system from attempting to mount these filesystems until the network has been enabled on the host system.

Comment: Corrected a few format and spelling errors. You should probably point out how and where to put that parameter using the configuration from the question as an example too.